# Opening Firefox with selenium error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to test out selenium, and the code asks me to run a script

`browser = webdriver.Firefox()`

However, this is the problem I get. Hope the gurus of the coding world can help me. This is Python 3 on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Please add gecko driver

Comment: You should to place the `geckodriver.exe` file in the same directory where your script is.

Comment: ok, so I will get the geckodriver, same directory as my script? If I am just testing from terminal, what would that be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox('C:\\Files\\geckodriver.exe')
```

[help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)